# Knockout js , mvc drop down default value is not selecting

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

it seems so simple but I am unable to do it.

I have bounded a Dropdown list with Json data from c#.

View page

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select data-bind="options: VehicleTypes, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue:'ID', optionsCaption: 'All', value: VehicleTypeId" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

Json call

Knockout Model

```
var baseModel = {
    VehicleTypeId: null,
    VehicleTypes: [],
}

 var viewModel =  ko.mapping.fromJS(baseModel);

 $.get(urlPath + "/GetVehicleTypes", function (data) {     
      viewModel.VehicleTypes(data);
 });
```

It does fill up the drop down and when I select a value in drop down value gets updated for VehicleTypeId.

My problem is I want to set a default value for my drop down list, I have googled it but nothing is workign for me

Data I am getting back in Json is as follow.

```
[{
    "ID": 32,
    "Name": "Vehicle 1"
}, {
    "ID": 30,
    "Name": "Vehicle 2"
}, {
    "ID": 31,
    "Name": "Vehicle 3"
}]
```

Comment: How have you tried to set the default value?

Answer (score 0):

Your VehicleTypes need to be in an observableArray and make sure you apply your bindings:

```
var baseModel = {
                // data
                VehicleTypeId: ko.observable(null),
                VehicleTypes: ko.observableArray([{
                    "ID": 32,
                    "Name": "Vehicle 1"
                }, {
                    "ID": 30,
                    "Name": "Vehicle 2"
                }, {
                    "ID": 31,
                    "Name": "Vehicle 3"
                }]),
            }

            ko.applyBindings(baseModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign a value to the VehicleTypeId so that the Default value is set.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/V5q9X/) is a working example.

```
function VehicleTypesViewModel(){
    var self = this;
  self.VehicleTypeId = null;
  self.VehicleTypes = [];   
}    
var viewModel =  new VehicleTypesViewModel();

$.get(urlPath + "/GetVehicleTypes", function (data) {     
  viewModel.VehicleTypeId = 32;
  viewModel.VehicleTypes = data;
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Off course its working on js fiddler. I have noticed my  VehicleTypeId becomes null when I am making $.get(urlPath + "/GetVehicleTypes", function (data) {     
  viewModel.VehicleTypeId = 32;
  viewModel.VehicleTypes = data;
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

Comment: Can you please post your jsFiddle. I have updated my jsFiddle to make an actual ajax call. It is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/V5q9X/2/

Comment: For me the solution was to initialize the Array with at least on item which as hot the same ID    then get data from an ajax call to fill up Array.

Same ID means if my ajax call was return array of IDs , 1001,1002 then I need initialize the Array like tis {"ID": 1001,     "Name": ""}


function VehicleTypesViewModel(){
    var self = this;
  self.VehicleTypeId = null;
  self.VehicleTypes = [{
                    "ID": 32,
                    "Name": "Vehicle 1"
                }];   
}