# knockout js select default value from mvc viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to set the default value of a KO select list selected item with a viewbag value.

This almost got me there but the value is hardcoded here.

[Knockout js , mvc drop down default value is not selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146318/knockout-js-mvc-drop-down-default-value-is-not-selecting)

```
function VehicleTypesViewModel(){
    var self = this;
  self.VehicleTypeId = null;
  self.VehicleTypes = [];   
}    
var viewModel =  new VehicleTypesViewModel();

$.get(urlPath + "/GetVehicleTypes", function (data) {     
  viewModel.VehicleTypeId = 32;
  viewModel.VehicleTypes = data;
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

The 32 in here is the selected value but I need this to be from the view bag. Will I have to make another ajax call to get and store the value from my viewbag in my KO viewmodel? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If this JS is in a `.js` file then you cannot use viewbag.  If the code is in a `.cshtml` file then you can inject with viewbag.

Comment: it is in a .js file thank you pretty much gave me my answer I will have to make another call in my KO file to bring in the viewbag item.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the viewbag data in the view (cshtml) with the attribute "data":

```
<div class="selected-vehicle" data-selected-id="@ViewBag.SelectedID"
```

The [data-*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) is the attribute of html, great place to store and update your view data.

Then in your .js file, you can just retrieve the data with jquery [data method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) call:

```
...
viewModel.VehicleTypeId = $(".selected-vehicle").data("selected-id");
```

Hope it helps.